# Adding GTK library to CLion

Tags: gtk3, clion

I'm new to **GTK** and I'm using **CLion** IDE to code.
I'm on Ubuntu and I've installed **libgtk-3.0-dev** .
The headers I've added to my code is:

`gtk-3.0`

`gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h`

but when I want to build the project I get this error :

> fatal error: gtk-3.0: No such file or directory

Comment: First, you should `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, not `gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h`. Next, you need to tell CLion where the header files are located. I am not familiar with CLion, but [their FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/) seems to contain some hint. You will also need to add some linker flags for the program to be successfully compiled. To get these flags you can use `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0` and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0`.

Comment: In Windows You Can See This Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463809/how-to-create-gtk3-application-with-c-language-in-windows-with-clion-ide

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I edited the CMakeLists file as [as mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/fracek/3323924) and it worked.

Here is my CMakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(gtk_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(gtk_test ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_link_libraries(gtk_test ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

I'm using **Clion 2016** and **libgtk-3.0-dev** on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: also works for CLion 2016.2 and gtk-3.0 on fedora 24.

Answer (score 1):

For GTK2, there is already a module call `FindGTK2` defined under `clion-2016.1.2/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindGTK2.cmake`. So just include it in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
include(FindGTK2)
if (GTK2_FOUND)
    include_directories(${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    link_libraries(${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
endif (GTK2_FOUND)
```